# Is it better to declare a variable in a loop or set the variable in the loop

Tags: c#, variables

I have a performance related query where i am trying to understand which logic would be faster.
My code is something like below

```
list<string> test=new list<string>();
foreach (DataTable Dt in Product_DataSet.Tables)
{
  foreach (DataRow dr in Product_DataTable.Rows)
  {
    test.add(dr["ColumnName"].tostring());
    // Code to concatenate all string in list test to single variable
    // Code to pass single variable to DB
  }
}
```

Here I encountered Problem as the list "test" kept growing. So i modified my inner loop like below

```
foreach (DataRow dr in Product_DataTable.Rows)
{
  test.add(dr["ColumnName"].tostring());
  // Code to concatenate all string in list test to single variable
  // Code to pass single variable to DB
  test.Clear();
}
```

Is this a better option than

```
foreach (DataRow dr in Product_DataTable.Rows)
{
  list<string> test=new list<string>();
  test.add(dr["ColumnName"].tostring());
  // Code to concatenate all string in list test to single variable
  // Code to pass single variable to DB
}
```

Comment: the last option there will not work - as you won't be 'adding' to the list, just creating a 'new' one for each element. )unless that's what you are trying to do)

Comment: I come from a Java background, but I guess I can do a cross-language comment: of course it's worse to recreate the list in the inner loop, you'll waste memory. It's way better to allocate it once, and clear it when necessary. As a side note, I'll move the clear in the outer loop (I guess you want to accumulate Strings in `test` in the inner loop).

Comment: Looks like they are going to be using then clearing? So... did you even try to benchmark and see which was faster?

Comment: After 40 questions you ought to know how to indent a piece of code here.

Comment: @terribleProgrammer - read the comments. The 3rd sample is fine (probably best)

Comment: From reading @crashmstr 's comment (about the clearing part), and understanding the OPs question better, I would agree with you Henk.

Comment: Samples 2 and 3 look like they do the same thing but the first does something very different.

Comment: Yep; think about `test.add(dr["ColumnName"].tostring();` as first of many, or some `foreach(column)`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last option is not comparable to the first because you are always creating a new list instead of filling the same. So at the end it contains only the rows of the last table and not of all tables.

So it depends on your needs.  If you only need one for each `DataTable` it is slightly better to use the list-constructor instead of [`List.Clear`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwb5h52a(v=vs.110).aspx) since the latter has to do more things.

So if you need one large list which contains all strings of all tables, why didn't you fill the list in the first place instead of loading the tables? You could have used a `DataReader`.

Comment: I have only one Datatabel. So i guess it will be better to declare a new list<string> for each new row in the datatable.

Comment: @MarsOne: if you only have one table it doesn't matter at all. But you should not create a list for every row, that seems to be pointless. For what do you need the list at all? If you want to concatenate multiple fields of a DataRow to a single variable you don't need a list but `String.Concat` (or `"a" + "b"`).

Comment: The i think its best to go with the .clear() option. I read another question on the same topic and i beleive this would be a better way to go

Comment: @MarsOne: `List.Clear` is not _better_ than `new List()` since it does more. The cost of `List.Clear`  depends on it's size. So if the list is already very large there might be a noticeable difference.

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me as though your two options are:

```
for  foreach (DataTable Dt in Product_DataSet.Tables)
{
    list<string> test=new list<string>();
    foreach (DataRow dr in Product_DataTable.Rows)
    {
        test.add(dr["ColumnName"].tostring();
    }
    //code to concat and send to db
}
```

or

```
list<string> test=new list<string>();
for  foreach (DataTable Dt in Product_DataSet.Tables)
{
    test.Clear();
    foreach (DataRow dr in Product_DataTable.Rows)
    {
        test.add(dr["ColumnName"].tostring();
    }
    //code to concat and send to db
}
```

I very much doubt there's much in it, performance-wise: in each case, all the contents will have to be garbage collected. But you could test it, with a lot of data, to see what happens.